# How to fix this error attribute chipText?

Tags: android, layout

I'll have some errors while building the application. I do not know how to fix this. Let me know if you know. I have given the layout code below.**<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip />** add I did this and that's when I got the Inda error.

Layout

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:chipBackgroundColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        app:chipText="Background Color" />

    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:chipText="Ripple Color"
        app:rippleColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />

    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:chipIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:chipText="Chip icon" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Error

```
\layout\include_recipe_detail.xml:400: AAPT: error: attribute chipText (aka com.app.yourrecipesapp:chipText) not found.
```